# How can I make an instance conform to "Comparable"?

Tags: swift

[image]Did somebody have an idea how can I fix this?

In the following Line:

```
//Entry Image Shared   
for shared in entryImagepostShared.sorted() {
    postetImageShared.append(shared)
}
```

I get an Error Like: Referencing instance method `sorted()` on `Sequence` requires that `Bool` conform to `Comparable`

```
postetImages.removeAll()
postetImageComment.removeAll()
postetImageID.removeAll()
postetImageShared.removeAll()
                
for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    
    guard let entryImageURL = document["imageURL"] as? [String],
    let entryImageComment = document["postText"] as? [String],
    let entryImagepostShared = document["postShared"] as? [Bool] else { return }
                    
     //Entry Image URL's
         for url in entryImageURL.sorted() {
             postetImages.append(url)
             }
         let count = postetImageURL.count
         imageURLCount += count
                    
         //Entry Image Comment
          for comment in entryImageComment.sorted() {
              postetImageComment.append(comment)
           }
                    
          //Entry Image Shared
          for shared in entryImagepostShared.sorted() {
              postetImageShared.append(shared)
          }
                    
      }
```

Comment: The error is saying that `sorted()` only works on an array of items that conform to the `Comparable` protocol and that `Bool` isn't one of those.  What is it that you'd like to have happen here?

Answer (score 1):

The Array's method `sorted()` requires that the array's values are comparable, i.e. there's a way to tell whether one value is less than another.

By default, the type `Bool` does not have this behavior.

If you need to sort an array of Bools, first you need to decide whether you want to see the `false` values first or the `true` values first.

Assuming the former, here are two ways to achieve this:

1. Use the `sorted(by:)` method which takes a closure. This closure takes two values and returns a Bool that indicates whether they are in increasing order:

```swift
let sorted = arrayOfBools.sorted { $0 == false || $1 == true }
```

2. Make the `Bool` conform to `Comparable` by implementing your own extension. Then you can just use `sorted()`:

```swift
extension Bool: Comparable {
    public static func < (lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) -> Bool {
        lhs == false || rhs == true
    }
}

let sorted1 = arrayOfBools.sorted()
```